# Se produce el error de unknowprovider al ejecutar un test con jasmine cod de google maps

Tags: google-maps

En un proyecto usando el componente Angular Google Maps:

```
var configureGoogleMaps = function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        libraries: 'geometry,visualization'
    });
}
configureGoogleMaps.$inject = ['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider'];

angular
    .module('shTools.Map', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
    .directive('map', mapDirective)
    .config(configureGoogleMaps);
```

donde mapDirective define un elemento HTML que contiene el componente de Google Maps.
Esto está funcionando como se espera. El problema es que cuando ejecuto un simple test usando Jasmine con Karma, obtengo el error Unknown provider: uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider. Por alguna razón no está siendo capaz de encontrar el proveedor.
He intentado crear un mock para forzar la creación de un proveedor con ese nombre, pero no ha funcionado:

```
angular.module('uiGmapgoogle-maps', [])
    .value('uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', {
        configure: function() {}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Los proveedores de AngularJs de inyectan de forma distinta al resto de servicios por lo que también hay que inyectarlos de forma especial cuando escribes las pruebas con Jasmine.
La forma de hacerlo consiste en crear un módulo falso en el que se inyecta el proveedor

```
beforeEach(function () {   
     // Módulo falso donde se inyecta el proveedor
     angular.module('testApp', function () {})
       .config(['bilingualButtonConfigProvider', function (provider) {
         bilingualButtonConfigProvider = provider;
       }]);
     // Inicializar módulos
     module('myApp', 'testApp');
});
```

También dejo un enlace que puede ayudarte:
http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/qTvMz/